# Difference between @Provider & javax.ws.rs.core.Feature in javax rest web services & their ordering

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey-2.0

I am experiencing a strange issue in our javax based rest web services. The api generates a json response by serializing a POJO class annotated using jaxb annotations. The rest api's are deployed on glassfish application server. The issue is that the api response is not consistent and changes on application restart. On making the api call, the json sometimes respects the jaxb annotations and sometimes the response is based on the getter/setter methods.

The pojo class is as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "records")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"number_of_records", "record"})
public class RecordsOutputXml {

    private int recordNum;
    private int numberOfRecords;

    public RecordsOutputXml() {
    //....
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "record")
    public int getRecordNum() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<RecordOutput> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "number_of_records")
    public int getNumber_of_records() {
        return numberOfRecords;
    }

    public void setNumberOfRecords(int numberOfRecords) {
        this.numberOfRecords = numberOfRecords;
    }
}
```

The two different responses are as below

1. Respecting the xml annotations

```json
{
    "number_of_records": 1,
    "record": 101
}
```

2. Fetching it from method names

```json
{
    "recordNum": 101,
    "number_of_records": 1,
}
```

On troubleshooting we understood this is because the order in which the implementations of `MessageBodyWriter` classes are loaded. On debugging we can see two implementations:

1. Custom implementation that extends `JacksonJsonProvider` and has `@Provider` annotation
2. `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature` enabled through "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames" init-param in the web.xml.

Depending on the order of these classes in the list (`_getMessageBodyReader()` method in `MessageBodyFactory`. The comparator doesn't seem to have any impact) the corresponding class is called. #1 does not respect `javax.xml.bind.annotation` while #2 registers `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` that interprets them.

I have a few questions

1. Is the above analysis correct?
2. Are `@Provider` & "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames" param in web.xml two ways to provide custom `MessageBodyWriter` implementations? Could they both be used simultaneously?
3. What are the possible solutions to resolve this?